# AndroidStudio 4.1 stable. Problem with the debugger

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Has anyone encountered a problem when updating AndroidStudio to 4.1? the debugger began to work worse: it skips breakpoints, you need to attach several times, on the contrary, it slows down in unnecessary places.

AndroidStudio EventLog:[image]

Evaluate doesn't work: [image]

Comment: The debugger in 4.1 won't attach for me period. Not sure why, troubleshooting has been difficult. Previous versions of Android Studio have worked fine. Both 4.1 beta and now public release will not attach the debugger period.

Comment: There are already some "tickets" regarding this specific bug in Android Studio's bug list, so I suppose someone will start to work on it. I know it is very frustrating to upgrade to a STABLE release and one of most useful features (breakpoints while debugging) won't work.....

Answer (score 1):

I had loads of issues with the new android 4.1 update I then updated the version to Android Studio 4.1 RC 2 and the issues stopped. https://developer.android.com/studio/archive the link to the download is there give it a try if it don't work just go back to 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Im facing same issues with 4.1 debugger. Performanse is terrible, most of the time it just does not work at all and I have to reattach it again and again.